# Safari overlaps header logo with body

Tags: css, wordpress, safari

I use Tao theme http://themeforest.net/item/tao-retina-responsive-wordpress-portfolio-theme/5913809

The website I have issue with is this http://www.thamon.co.uk/
If you open the page with Safari, it overlaps the logo with the body of all pages.

In styles.css I have he following code associated with the header that I believe is somewhat relevant to the problem

```
.header {
        position: relative; 
    }
        .header .header-primary-content { 
            display: table;
            width: 100%;
            position: relative; 
            padding: 10px 0;
            margin-bottom: 10px;

            border-bottom: 1px solid #e6e6e6; 
        } 
            /* Border shadow */
            .header .header-primary-content:after { 
                content: " ";
                position: relative;
                z-index: -1; 
                bottom: -2px;
                left: 0;
                width: 100%;
                height: 1px;

                background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .5);
            }
                .logo, .header-buttons {
                    display: table-cell;
                    vertical-align: middle;

                }

                /**
                 * Logo
                 */
                .logo {
                    width: 70%;
                }
                    .logo a {
                        display: inline-block;

                    position: relative;

                        width: 120px;
                        height: 40px;
                        margin-left: 410px;

                        vertical-align: middle

                        color: #444652;
                        text-shadow: 1px 1px #fff, 0px 0px #0E0E0E, 2px 3px 1px #E3E3E3;
                        font: normal 400 60px 'Merriweather', Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
                    }
                        .no-touch .logo a:hover {
                            animation: tinywiggle 220ms ease-out;
                        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You put a height of 40px on .logo a when the height of the logo is 120px x 147px. Try matching the height of the .logo a with the img instead or remove the height from the .logo a

Comment: Thank your for your advice. However, neither deleting the height: 40px command, nor adding a test value of height: 400px doesn't seem to change anything in safari.

Comment: Try removing the height, I have checked it myself and it fixes it in safari.

Comment: My friend, could you please send me the extract from the code where you deleted the height. I dunno why, but for me deleting this line doesn't change a thing. Did you see the problem I stated in safari before you deleted the height?

Comment: logo a {
         display: inline-block;

     position: relative;
      
         width: 120px;
  
      margin-left: 410px;
      
      vertical-align: middle

      color: #444652;
      text-shadow: 1px 1px #fff, 0px 0px #0E0E0E, 2px 3px 1px #E3E3E3;
      font: normal 400 60px 'Merriweather', Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
        }
         .no-touch .logo a:hover {
       animation: tinywiggle 220ms ease-out;
      }

Comment: I just checked, and I'm guessing it's working fine now? Since it seems to have the height updated and it's displaying in Safari now for me just fine.

Comment: can you please send the screen shot of what you see in safari and safari's version to e.myshkin@thamon.co.uk?

Comment: I still see it normal in Chrome, but in Safari the logo is cut in half by the border of header... What is wrong?

Comment: I'm using 6.1.3 version of Safari, which one are you using? It's displaying same as Chrome, now that the height hasn't been assigned. Part of it is, some browsers will be a lot more picky about having things assigned the right size, so you should always do that.

Comment: Nicholas, I have a version 7.0.3 and this is what I keep seeing http://imgur.com/0yMUNil

Comment: I have the same issue until the height on the .logo a was removed. Can you do me a favor a go into your inspect elements and inspect the .logo a and see if it still has the height. It might be stuck in your cache, and either you need to do a hard refresh or clear your cache.

Comment: Thank you Nicholas. Hard reseting the Safari with clearing the cash made the trick. I guess the new users will see everything correctly now. Thank you really much for your support :) Have a pleasant evening!